# Changing input url in MediaLive

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-media-live

I'm trying to update an Input MediaLive URL using `boto3` in python.

The input is an `URL_PULL` type (HLS) and is attached to a channel, and I think it's the source of my issue.

```
account = { all credentials and stuff }
url = 'https://mynew/supercool/hls/playlist.m3u8'
client = boto3.client("medialive",
                      aws_access_key_id=account['access_key'],
                      aws_secret_access_key=account['key_secret'],
                      region_name=account['region_name'])

input_id = 1234567
client.update_input(InputId=input_id, Sources=[{'Url': url}])
```

The code is working fine, but I get this error, and I don't know how to handle it :

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the UpdateInput
>   operation: You cannot change the input class of an input while it's
>   attached to a channel. Please detach the input from the channel in
>   order to switch its class.

**Question :** Which workflow should I use to update an input that is already attached to a channel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS API expects 2 urls when updating an input, main and backup.

`client.update_input(InputId=input_id, Sources=[{'Url': url},{'Url': url}])`

Answer (score 1):

If the input class is STANDARD_INPUT you will need 2 URLs,  but if you are using a SINGLE_INPUT class you only need 1 URL.

If you only need 1 URL you can create the inputs as SINGLE_INPUT but your channel will have to be single (SINGLE_PIPELINE) instead of STANDARD.

Also, single channels are cheaper than Standard ones!